# Why is it returning a totally empty value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 9876
ADDR = ("127.0.0.1",4444)
BUFSIZE = 4096

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serv.bind(ADDR)
serv.listen(5)

print('listening ...')
conn, addr = serv.accept()
print('client connected ... ', addr)

def download():
  while True:
    print("Got succesfully to the function")
    data = conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
    print(data)
    if not data: break
    myfile = open(command[1], 'wb')
    myfile.write(data)
    print ('writing file ....')
    myfile.close()
    print ('finished writing file')



while True:
  command = input(">> ") #Basicamente lo que esta pasando aqui:
  command = command.encode() #Se encodea para mandarlo
  conn.send(command) #Se manda bien
  command = command.decode() #Se desencodea
  command = command.split(" ") #Y se hace en una lista para los "ifs"
  data = conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
  print("Recieved package")
  if command[0] == "download":
    download()
  else:
    print(data)

conn.close()
print ('client disconnected')
```

Client:

```
import socket



HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9876
ADDR = ("127.0.0.1",4444)
BUFSIZE = 4096
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

recibio = client.recv(BUFSIZE).decode()
recibio = recibio.split(" ")


def mandar_archivo():   
    bytes = open(recibio[1], 'rb').read()
    print(recibio[1])
    print(len(bytes))
    client.sendall(bytes)

mandar_archivo()
client.close()
```

Everything seems to be going just fine until it gets to the

```
bytes = open(recibio[1], 'rb').read()
```

part of the client. I say this because, when I try to print the value of bytes, I'm getting an empty value. Same thing happens if I print data on the Server. I've also checked and the `recibio[1]` value which is just fine, identical to the on I sent on the server side.

What is causing this?

Comment: So the client i receiving a filename/path - and is that accessible at the client to open?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same folder.

Comment: Are client and server on different machines? And this folder is accessible on exactly the same path on both?

Comment: They are on the same machine and the client program is inside the same folder as the file whereas the server is on another.

Comment: Is it an absolute path? So if you write a simple, minimal python script and all it does is use exactly the same filename/path, opens it and prints the content in exactly the same way, does it work?

Comment: Yes that was what was bugging me :/ I mean, it doesn't print out anything cause its a png but at least the file transfer works perfecly. On the simple program I mean. Actually, here's what Im basing my code of: https://gist.github.com/marvin/4318413